# How to migrate from transmission to vuze?

Tags: configuration, bittorrent, transmission, migration, vuze

Googling for "migrate from transmission to vuze" gives me such gems as:

[Migrate from Vuze to Transmission](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?t=9869)

Is `vuze` so unloved that no one stays with it?  Currently using both, would like to click a button for migration to `vuze`.  By which I mean:

- get magnet link from transmission
- add magnet link to vuze
- verify data
- remove magnet from transmission
- uninstall transmission

Comment: As written, this seems like a feature request for the Vuze developers more than a support topic.

Comment: not really, I'm sure someone somewhere has migrated from transmission to vuze.  Maybe many people.  Perhaps they'll share their insights.